# How to understand "she'd have a job hiding" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “We were just talking about the night when Mr. Crouch turned up on the grounds,” said Fudge. “It was you who found him, was it not?”
>
> “Yes,” said Harry. Then, feeling it was pointless to pretend that he
>   hadn't overheard what they had been saying, he added, “I didn't see
>   Madame Maxime anywhere, though, and **she'd have a job hiding**, wouldn't
>   she?”
>
> Dumbledore smiled at Harry behind Fudge's back, his eyes twinkling.
>
> “Yes, well,” said Fudge, looking embarrassed, ...

I don't quite understand "she'd have a job hiding". Does it mean hiding is her job or something? What does it mean exactly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A job can be a single piece of work, or a task. In UK conversation, to "have a job" doing something can mean to find doing that thing difficult or impossible. It would be a hard job to do it. Is Madame Maxine very large? That might explain why she would "have a job" hiding somewhere.

> Job
>   2.2 informal
>   in singular
>   A difficult task. 
>   ‘we thought you'd have a job getting there’

[Job (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/job)

Comment: Is this particularly for UK English?

Comment: I am a British English speaker; I do not know if it is used in other English zones; Macmillan and Longman dictionaries both say it is "British". I would guess it is common in Australia & New Zealand. Maybe a US English speaker will comment.

Comment: "She'd **have a job** *doing something*" (BrE). "It **would be a job** *to do something*" (BrE/AmE); "It **would be a lot of work** *to do something*" (AmE)

Comment: All equally valid in UK English, too.